# How to develop single page application using JSP?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-boot, design-patterns

I want to develop an application using spring boot, jsp, bootstrap and hibernate. Where my each jsp page have the header, footer and left pane same but only the middle section get change based on the functionality. And i dont want to create each page with copying the same all over and even dont want impact application performance by adding all the UI dependencies in each and every JSP. 
So can someone please suggest me the best approach to deal with it.

I searched and find the Angular JS an react JS options, but I already have one application built in Spring 4, JSP, Hibernate technology stack and one which i have to develop is going to integrate with old one, so I think technology stack may impact the integration. For integration i am thinking about maven multimodule project.

Hence I need suggestion as i am in initial stages of development .

Comment: Use apache tile3

Comment: Hello @SumeshTG thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: welcome bro.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make use of `jsp:include`; Here is one tutorial but I'm sure there's many others. https://www.roseindia.net/jsp/include-tag-jsp.shtml
Example:
`<jsp:include page="includes/header.jsp" flush="true">
    <jsp:param name="title" value="Example" />
</jsp:include>`
header.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>${ param.title }</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url 
    value="/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>" />
</head>
```

Comment: jsp:include will work for static content, but i want to add all the UI related dependencies to my common jsp and when i will include that jsp to other jsp will those dependencies accessible to me? Like common.jsp have jquery.js and when i will include this common.jsp to home.jsp, will the jquey accessible to home.jsp ?

Comment: Yes. As an example you can create a header.jsp and footer.jsp which include all your imports (css, js, etc) and then include that jsp into your pages. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, your example will help me,so waiting for your example

Comment: So using jsp:include tag, on every page load all the UI dependencies will get downloaded or just at once .. As per my understanding on every page load all the dependencies will get downloaded and it may impact the page performance. If it is so, how can I reduce dependency download overhead?

Comment: You could always use ajax to load the content. But I think you're trying to get a jsp based Web app to behave like a React or Angular app, which is not possible. You have to use some sort of template system rather than actually have a SPA.